# Connect to Cisco VPN through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vpn, cisco

We have a server which can be connected through **Cisco VPN** connection. We need to fetch data from that server to our local client. VPN connection is established after authentication. I want to make this VPN connection process automated and fetch data. Is this possible to automate this process? Can we use C#.net for this?

Comment: You can do it through the command line. See http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client46/administration/guide/vcAch5.html

Comment: @Tony post that as an answer?

Comment: Okay More link than answer really. There again this guy doesn't seem big on accept anyway. 33% !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will take a bit of working out but you can use the Cisco VPN through the command line, so what you want should be doable. Have to find out where stuff has been installed etc. But mainly donkey work.

For info about what you can and can't do at the command line, I googled Cisco VPN comandline and found this.
[Cisco VPN through the command line](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client46/administration/guide/vcAch5.html)

Comment: I want even authentication to be automated.

Comment: That means storing the password somewhere to use at the command line, which is well iffy. Or the boys who run your network setting up Cisco for SSO, which I know nowt about and is not a topic for this site anyway...